# Force ARC to retain an object reference by a void pointer

Tags: objective-c, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

Let's say that I have this property:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) void*** array;
```

And init the array with objective-c objects:

```
- (id) init
{
    if(self=[super init])
    {
        array= malloc(10*sizeof(void**));
        for(NSUInteger i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            array[i]= malloc(10*sizeof(void*));
            for(NSUInteger j=0; j<10; j++)
            {
                array[i][j]= (__bridge_retained void*) @"Hello";
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then I found that the object are not really retained:

```
 Custom* c=[Custom new];
 NSLog(@"%@",(__bridge NSString*)c.array[40][40]);
```

This prints (null), I thought that the bridge retained cast did force to retain the object, how to go around this?

Comment: I'm confused. Why would not not just type it correctly?

Comment: Why would you want a pointer like that? Why not use NSArray, you seem to hold NSObjects in it anyway? Also it's probably printing nil or other garbage because you don't have 40 elements in it.

Comment: Indded this was the problem.I didn't use id just to test how "forcing ARC to retain objects".

Comment: @Valentin Radu indeeed I was goind out of bounds, you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting nil (or random garbage) is because you allocated and populated your array with 10 elements and then you try to access the 40th element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use 'id' type instead of 'void' type.

'id' is also abstract.